# Add a late answer to an existing, or create a new self-answered question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, self-answer, late-answers

I don't have a blog but I came up with a good idea that I want to share. At first I was going to write it as a Q/A-style post but then realized that this is a duplicate question, just that none of the existing questions have it as the answer.

Is it a good idea to post a (late) answer to a answered question (maybe months ago)? Or would it be better to post a new question that I self-answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, why not? If you have a good answer that is adding new details that are not present in other answers, by all means post that answer.

This will bump the question up the Active Questions lists and give people chance to see your answer.

Worth to mention that we have bounty reasons like "Improve details - The current answers do not contain enough detail" exactly for such cases.

Comment: ok, but what if there are duplicated questions already, which one should I choose to answer?

Comment: @alrz the one asked in the most clear way, possibly the oldest, then flag the others as duplicates if you want to be extra helpful. :)